# how to replace a SOQL query with Dynamic query?

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

Here is the code I am trying to convert to dynamic query-

```java
List<RecordType> jobRecordTypes  = [SELECT Id, DeveloperName 
                                    FROM   RecordType 
                                    WHERE (DeveloperName=:FieldPro_Library.WORK_ORDER_RECORD_TYPE 
                                        OR DeveloperName=:FieldPro_Library.MAKE_READY_RECORD_TYPE) 
                                        AND SObjectType=:FieldPro_Library.RESOURCE_REQUEST_API_NAME];
```

I am confused how to implement the OR AND logic into single dynamic query

Example of dynamic query I want-

```java
List<RecordType> jobRecordTypes = Schema.SObjectType.RecordType.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(FieldPro_Library.WORK_ORDER_RECORD_TYPE).getRecordTypeId();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example of how you can make use of `Database.query(...)` with a prebuilt SOQL extended by an input parameter representing the WHERE clause.

```
String whereClause = '(DeveloperName=:FieldPro_Library.WORK_ORDER_RECORD_TYPE' +
        ' OR DeveloperName=:FieldPro_Library.MAKE_READY_RECORD_TYPE)' +
        ' AND SObjectType=:FieldPro_Library.RESOURCE_REQUEST_API_NAME';

List<RecordType> recordTypes = getRecordTypes(whereClause);

private static List<RecordType> getRecordTypes(String whereClause) {
    String query = 'SELECT Id, DeveloperName' +
            ' FROM RecordType';

    if (whereClause != null)  query = query + ' WHERE ' + whereClause;
    return Database.query(query);
}
```

This allows you to call the private method with many filter variations on the shared RecordType object. You can also extend the method to receive a LIMIT variable if needed and then apply such value to the SOQL.